# Ajax Javascript Last data inserted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get last data that are inserted into a table in realtime, I am using ajax to refresh data every 5 seconde.
So first of all I am calling a php script to get current last Id, and place it in the variable "last"
But the variable "last" is undefined even if its a Global Variable

```
 var last = 0;
var isChanged =0;
window.setInterval(function(){

    alert(last);
    $.post(
        "controller/ajaxComment.php",
        { act: "getLastCommentId", id_post: params.id },

        function(data) {
            data = data.toString();


            if(isChanged == 0)
            {
                last = data;
                isChanged = 1;
            }
           // alert("data" + data + "last" + last);
            last = 3 ;
            if(last != data)
            {
                var last = data;
                $.post(
                    "controller/ajaxComment.php",
                    {
                        act:"getLastComment" , id_post: params.id
                    },
                    function(info)
                    {
                        $("#result").append(info);
                    }
                )
            }

        }
    );
}, 5000);
```

Comment: why last is declared again in ajaxComment call??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have 2 variables named `last`.

One is global and one is scoped in the interval function `var last = data;`.

Remove `var` from the one inside the timer if you want to update the global variable